# Как подогнать изображение под данные мне размеры?

Tags: css3, html5

Есть изображение (1775*1723px) я через background-position оставил "видимой" лишь часть изображения, но оно осталось огромным, то-есть смотрю через просмотр кода и оно все равно занимает те же 1775*1723px, я явно попал в тупик)

https://yadi.sk/i/CChYpesbeWtIcg - вот psd макет, который я выбрал для хоть какой то практики во время обучения и подкрепления изученного материала.

[image: Это картинка с которой возникли проблемы]

```css
.vso_1 {
  background-image: url(../images/Vector_Smart_Object.png);
  background-position: -1164px -946px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 1775px;
  height: 1723px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

body {
  width: 3543px;
  height: 2126px;
  background-color: #4b58df;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>...</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="vso_1"></div>
</body>




</html>
```

В общем мне нужно чтобы это изображение приобрело разрешение 'видимой' его части, которую я оставил через background-position. То-есть адаптировалось к размеру окна, в общем даже не знаю как объяснить то что мне нужно, ибо знания во всем еще достаточно скудны..

Comment: Через редактор вырежьте этот кусок картинки и управляйте размерами без проблем :)

Comment: Какой бы вы размер у изображения не ставили, хоть в пикселях, хоть в процентах - загружать браузер всегда будет оригинал и в консоли при наведении будет показываться отображаемый размер и размер оригинала. Если вопрос в изменении размера изображения стоит в оптимизации для адаптива (загрузка меньшего количества контента для телефонов и планшетов) - то вам нужно для разных разрешений нарезать разных размеров изображений.